# Create & Authenticate a new User from a different controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, claims-based-identity

I have a landing page where an anonymous visitor can fill a form to perform an action.
On the controller side, let's call it the `VoteController`, I want to register and login the user together with the action business logic (voting).

I have tried with the following code, and it seems to work, but whenever the user continues navigating the site, It gets error on each page that contains a `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()`, it seems that something went wrong with claims.

```
var claims = new List<Claim>();
claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, a.UserName));
claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, model.Email));

var id = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

var ctx = Request.GetOwinContext();
var authenticationManager = ctx.Authentication;
authenticationManager.SignIn(id);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which error you got?

Comment: Whenever the user finds a page with a call to @Html.AntyForgeryToken(), the following exception occurs:
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.WebPages.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: A claim of type 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier' was not present on the provided ClaimsIdentity.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier` property within the `Application_Start` method in `global.asax.cs`, for example:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
         AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier;
}
```